retrouver ubuntu 22 04
Translated from French to English:
I upgraded from Ubuntu studio 22 04 to Ubuntu 24 04 using the proposed upgrade. Since then, normal Ubuntu (non-studio) present on the disk no longer appears in the opening choice that I had before when opening my PC. How can I find it again?

This is an English only site, can you translate your post please...

You should read this Ubuntu Studio article about upgrading Ubuntu Studio from version 22.04 to 24.04

@graham Please see https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19895/124466 about translating posts

@ArchismanPanigrahi Thanks for the link to meta. My only comment to that is damned if you do, damned if you don't. The author of the accepted response also suggested that we should look for ways to avoid just deleting posts where the question may have wider value to the community. I thought this one did, hence translating it and providing a Ubuntu based response. Coincidentally, I understood the OP's question as a French speaker and a resident in France.

I also recall an earlier meta post suggesting that where a post is translated, the original text should be included. I did that but another user came along and edited out the original text. Oh well....

@graham If you are a native speaker then it is fine, in my opinion.
